# Why is $CONDA_PREFIX set to $BUILD_PREFIX during the build process of conda-build?

Tags: python, conda-build

I have following build.sh and want to install my python package by simply copying the $RECIPE_DIR to $CONDA_PREFIX/...

```
#!/bin/sh

# Variables
# package_name="filip_test_package"
dir_in_conda=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/$PKG_NAME

# Install
echo "Installing"
echo $CONDA_PREFIX
echo $RECIPE_DIR
echo $PKG_NAME

mkdir $dir_in_conda
cp -RT $RECIPE_DIR/$PKG_NAME $dir_in_conda
```

However, during executiong I get following stacktrace. It seems that $CONDA_PREFIX is replaced with $BUILD_PREFIX but I do not know why. Do I need to set something in my meta.yaml?

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
source tree in: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/filip_test_package_1617799915931/work
export PREFIX=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/filip_test_package_1617799915931/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol
export BUILD_PREFIX=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/filip_test_package_1617799915931/_build_env
export SRC_DIR=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/filip_test_package_1617799915931/work
Installing
$BUILD_PREFIX
/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/python_project
filip_test_package
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/filip_test_package_1617799915931/_build_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/filip_test_package’: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 481, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 470, in execute
    outputs = api.build(args.recipe, post=args.post, test_run_post=args.test_run_post,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 186, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 3068, in build_tree
    packages_from_this = build(metadata, stats,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2191, in build
    utils.check_call_env(cmd, env=env, rewrite_stdout_env=rewrite_env,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 412, in check_call_env
    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 392, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, _args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-o', 'errexit', '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/filip_test_package_1617799915931/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. Installing anaconda, instead of miniconda solves my problem.
Note that reinstalling clean miniconda did not solve it.